# How to increase GnuGPG passphrase dialog box timeout?

Tags: gpg

The GnuGPG passphrase prompt dialog box timesout after 60 seconds.

How do I increase the timeout period ?

(Just to clarify that I am *not* looking for `default-cache-ttl` but the timeout of the passphrase dialog box itself. I am using GnuPG v2.2.23 on Fedora 33).

[image]

Comment: In `gpg-agent.conf` set `default-cache-ttl `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase timeout period of passphrase prompt dialogue box by adding the following line to `$HOME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`[0]

```
pinentry-timeout 120
```

Now the passphrase popup will wait for `120` seconds. To load the above config restart `gpg-agent` by running[1]

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

`gpg-agent` will be started automatically on running `gpg` command.

[0] https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg24/gpg-agent.1.html

[1] https://superuser.com/a/1150399